# How to solve question involving integration and Sigma notations

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

The general term for summation of n terms is given and the nth term is given .Finding the relation between them when n tends to infinity.

> Let $$
> S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\tan^{-1} \frac{k}{n}}{n}
> \quad \text{and} \quad 
> T_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\tan^{-1} \frac{k}{n}}{n}
> \quad \text{for}~n \in \mathbb{N}
> $$
> then which of the following statements is false?
>
> - (A) $S_n > \frac{\pi - \ln 4}{4}$
> - (B) $T_n < \frac{\pi - \ln 4}{4}$
> - (C) $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n > \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$
> - (D) none of these

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can it be solved without actually integrating the inverse function so formed?

Comment: If we let k/n as x and treating n as constant ,we can actually convert it into an integral.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those "self-reference" questions, where (D) refers in part to itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that$$I:=\int_0^1\arctan xdx=[x\arctan x-\tfrac12\ln(1+x^2)]_0^1=\frac{\pi-\ln 4}{4}.$$[As you noted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), $S_n>I>T_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n=I$, so the answer is (C).

I doubt we can verify (A), (B) are true without evaluating $I$, but since $S_n-T_n=\frac{\pi}{4n}$, (C) is false. So if we exploit the fact that the question's options tell us at most one of (A)-(C) are false, we can avoid evaluating $I$, or even noticing an integral is comparable to the sequences $S_n,\,T_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer